# Cannot see my text after clicking on burger Menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, dom-events

I have three files index.html,  style.css, app.js.

Trying to make a **responsive layout**.

I have set the opacity to 0 in my CSS file under  **.nav-link li**.
When I click on burger icon text I want to animate i.e **opacity of text should turn from 0 to 1 (check the @keframe navLinkFade)** and then the text will appear. **But this doesn't happen. Why**?

I have called all the functions properly in **app.js** I guess please have a look at it.

When I make opacity to 1 in CSS it works fine, but this does not give me the fading effect.

Image before clicking the burger menu:

[image: https://imgur.com/fzye2Hy]

Image after clicking on the burger menu

[image: https://imgur.com/uQwTUOt]

index.html

```js
  const navSlide = () => {
      const burger = document.querySelector(".burger");
      const nav = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
      const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");
    
      burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
        nav.classList.toggle("nav-avtive");
    
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
          if (link.style.animation) {
            link.style.animation = "";
          } else {
            link.style.animation = "navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s";
          }
        });
      });
    };
    navSlide();
```

```css
  * {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    nav {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 8vh;
      font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
      background-color: black;
    }
    .logo {
      color: whitesmoke;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 5px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    
    .nav-links {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
      width: 30%;
    }
    .nav-links li {
      list-style: none;
    }
    .nav-links a {
      color: rgb(240, 172, 0);
      text-decoration: none;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    .burger {
      display: none;
    }
    .burger div {
      background-color: whitesmoke;
      height: 3px;
      width: 25px;
      margin: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
      .nav-links {
        width: 60%;
      }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 92vh;
        top: 8vh;
        background-color: black;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
      }
      .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      .burger {
        display: block;
      }
    }
    .nav-avtive {
      transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    
    @keyframes navLinkFade {
      from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
      }
      to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
      }
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Document</title>
        
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav>
          <div class="logo">
            <h4>The Nav</h4>
          </div>
          <ul class="nav-links">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
    
          <div class="burger">
            <div class="line1"></div>
            <div class="line2"></div>
            <div class="line3"></div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        
        </div>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I want the burgerMenu to show text using navLinkFade

Comment: Your animation does not trigger `li` opacity change. Update css to `.nav-links li { opacity: 0; transition: all 2s ease; }`, `.nav-links.nav-avtive li { opacity: 1; }`

Answer (score 4):

The ***.nav-links li*** `opacity: 0` is the main issue. Change the opacity and it works.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px)
.nav-links li {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And for animation the string should be wrapped by **ES6 `**  instead of double quote. Because inside the double quote the logical calculation or variables do not work. Inside double or single quote ***${index / 7}*** is considered as a string.

```
link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`
```

Comment: Hey, it works, but I don't get the animation. I am talking about this animation
Please watch this video at 29:17 to 29:21
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gXkqy0b4M5g

Comment: Your string formation is wrong. It should be \`navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s\`

Comment: Thank you very much man, really appreciate your help. God bless u

Answer (score 1):

`link.style.animation = "navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s";` the animation string does not get interpolated because you're using double quotes, you meed to use back-ticks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: It still doesn't work, Thanx for the correcting me though

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the double quotes to back tick

```
link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7}s`;
```